# Is there a way to mark audio file

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, html5-audio

If I have a mp3 audio file (imported on my website), is there a way to mark it. I mean that whenever I hit pause, I want to mark that time in the audio file and store that it in an array. Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

vid.onpause = function() {

  alert(this.currentTime);

};
```

Save `this.currentTime` wherever you would like to.

Hope this Helps

**Just for Reference**, have a look at HTML5 Video events in action:

http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html